# How to extract a word in java after a given word in using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract a word after a given word. 
eg: if my string is "http://localhost:8080/api/rest/loan/application/1007/applicant/951/pan", then i want to extract the word which ever comes after `application` (assume application comes only once in the string).

In this case I want to extract 1007. For now I have tried this using Java

`(.*?^)(.*?)application/[0-9]*`.

This is giving me output as `http://localhost:8080/api/rest/loan/application/1007`. But I want only 1007 as my output.

Comment: You don't need regex in this case. You can use a combination of `substring` and `indexof`. You could also treat the URL as a `Path` (definitely hackish and not the recommended usage) if you know the index of the element relative to the name count in advance.

Comment: Is your input always URL?

Comment: Also can your URL look like `http://server.com/application/index.php?ord=asc&date=today#info`? What is *expected* result if word would also be `application`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use positive look behind to ensure the matched text is preceded by `application/` using this regex,

```
(?<=application/)[^/]+
```

Here, `[^/]+` part will capture any text except `/`, giving you your desired text `1007`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ek7Rc6/1)**

Java code,

```
String s = "http://localhost:8080/api/rest/loan/application/1007/applicant/951/pan";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=application/)[^/]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Prints,

```
1007
```

Another easier and more performant way to do the same task would be to use following grouping pattern,

```
/application/([^/]+)
```

and capture the contents of group1.

**[Regex Demo with grouping pattern](https://regex101.com/r/ek7Rc6/2)**

Notice, this is much faster as well as will work broadly as look arounds are sometimes not supported in some dialects.

Java code,

```
String s = "http://localhost:8080/api/rest/loan/application/1007/applicant/951/pan";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/application/([^/]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Prints,

```
1007
```

Comment: It's better than mine version +1

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
    String a = "http://localhost:8080/api/rest/loan/application/1007/applicant/951/pan";
    a = a.replaceAll("(.*?^)(.*?)application/", "");
    String[] b = a.split("/");
    System.out.println(b[0]);
```

string `replace` function takes exact string as input while `replaceAll` takes a regex as an input argument.